# Failed to compile in react

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors

stefan1377
1m

Hello everybody… I just started my react project… I moved two files(App.css,App.js) from src/ to src/components/App. I updated index.js what is in src/ folder to this `import App from "./components/App/App";` But I got this error message on the browser

```
 Failed to compile
./src/components/App/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './logo.svg' in 'C:\Users\rapid\Documents\Codecademy\reactapps\ravenous\src\components\App'
```

Any anyone know the solution for this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Where is `logo.svg` located?

Comment: in src/ folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you move your App.js to another folder, but you did not move logo.svg to the same folder as App.js and it is located in src folder.

If this is the case, either move logo.svg to the same folder as App.js or in App.js change  import './logo.svg' to import '../../logo.svg'